# Drawing a Path in XAML (with binding) vs. C#. One works, one doesn't

Tags: c#, wpf, shapes

I'm completely new to programming in general, but I've been teaching myself C# for about 6 months. Currently working on WPF/XAML. I'm trying to learn about rendering shapes in WPF.

I have a Path created in a custom class that my AllocationCanvas is binding to in the XAML below. For whatever reason, it just won't draw, even though I know the binding is set up correctly.

```
<Canvas x:Name="AllocationCanvas"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Width="Auto"
                    Height="Auto"
                    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                         AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
    <Path Data="{Binding Path=chartmaker.myPath}"/>

</Canvas>
```

However, if I call AllocationCanvas.Children.Add(myPath) it works fine. What am I missing?

```
public class ChartMaker {

    private Dictionary<string, double> chartData;
    Portfolio P;
    public PathFigure arcs { get; set; }
    private PathGeometry pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
    public Path myPath { get; set; }

    public ChartMaker(Portfolio portfolio) {
        P = portfolio;
        chartData = new Dictionary<string, double>();

        myPath = new Path();
        myPath.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        myPath.Fill = Brushes.MediumSlateBlue;
        myPath.StrokeThickness = 4;

        arcs = new PathFigure();
        arcs.StartPoint = new Point(100, 100);
        arcs.IsClosed = true;
        arcs.Segments.Add(new ArcSegment(new Point(200, 200), new Size(50, 50), 0, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, true));
        arcs.Segments.Add(new ArcSegment(new Point(150, 350), new Size(10, 10), 0, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, true));

        pathGeometry.Figures.Add(arcs);

        myPath.Data = pathGeometry;

        ProcessChartData();
    }

    private void ProcessChartData() {
        double TotalMarketValue = P.Positions.Sum(position => position.MarketValue);

        foreach (Position position in P.Positions) {
            double weight = position.MarketValue/TotalMarketValue;
            chartData.Add(position.Ticker, weight);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding your `Data` DP of `Path` to object of type `Path` which won't work.

`Data` is `Geometry` type so you need to bind to an object which will return `Geometry` and not `Path`.

Make your `pathGeomerty` a `property` and bind with it -

```
public PathGeometry Geometry
{
   get
   {
      return pathGeometry ;
   }
}
```

XAML -

```
<Path Data="{Binding Path=chartmaker.Geometry}"/>
```